# Rust how to resolve type annotations in a static function call of some struct

Tags: rust, generic-programming

In general I know how to resolve types by using `::<T>` syntax or `<T as X>::` syntax. But not in this particular example.
How can I get the following code to compile?

```rust
fn main() {
    Namespace::apply(&mut Obj1 { v: vec![1, 2, 3] });
}

pub trait Func<T> {
    fn func(data: &mut T);
}

pub trait Apply<T, X: Func<T>> {
    fn apply(data: &mut T);
}

pub struct Namespace {}

pub struct Obj1 {
    v: Vec<i32>,
}
pub struct Obj2 {
    v: Vec<i32>,
}

impl Func<Obj1> for Namespace {
    fn func(data: &mut Obj1) {
        println!("FuncA()");
        data.v.clear(); // do stuff with data
        println!("{:?}", data.v);
    }
}
impl Func<Obj2> for Namespace {
    fn func(data: &mut Obj2) {
        println!("FuncB()");
        data.v.push(4); // do stuff with data
        println!("{:?}", data.v);
    }
}
impl<T, X: Func<T>> Apply<T, X> for Namespace {
    fn apply(data: &mut T) {
        println!("apply()");
        X::func(data);
    }
}
```

I get the following error:

```
error[E0282]: type annotations needed
  --> src\lib.rs:18:9
   |
18 |         Namespace::apply(&mut Obj1 { v: vec![1, 2, 3] });
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ cannot infer type for `X`

error: aborting due to previous error

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0282`.
```

I tried the `::<Obj1, Func<Obj1>>::` syntax in various places around `apply` but keep getting errors.

Context:
This is mostly an abstract question, I'm not trying to achieve anything concrete behind the scenes. In answering, please assume that I am just a weird person who thinks OOP is evil and does not want to use self/&self in the trait. My idea was first to define some method as a function `func` in some placeholder `Namespace` structure, implement it for different objects, then I wanted to define an `apply` function that uses the `func` method in an abstract generic way. If you have better suggestions on how to achieve this goal, I'm happy to hear them.

Comment: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=ecb2e679afd00a00bdba3a840d14e32b, but I don't think you can make this compile your code don't make much sense specially `X` does not appear in `Apply` I'm surprise this trait definition compile. You are trying something very advanced.

Comment: Yeah, the X requirement in the trait is just a hint that the implementation of the function might use some X::functions .  Actually I managed to make it compile by adding a X parameter to apply, as type can be then infered, but I dislike this solution as the X parameter is not truly needed. I want a solution without other parameters than T data

Comment: My philosophy here is to try to write generic contract based code, on functions that manipulate objects. where functions and objects live independently from each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `X` type isn't declared in a function signature or struct parameter, therefore, the compiler is unable to infer the appropriated type.

To circumvent this problem, you need to explicit tell the desired `X` and since the trait function has no receiver (`self`, `&self`, `&mut self`, `self: Pin<Self>`), it is possible to "cast" the concrete type.

```rust
<Namespace as Apply<Obj1, Namespace>>::apply(&mut Obj1 { v: vec![1, 2, 3] });
```

Comment: This works. You can also just write ```<Namespace as Apply<_, Namespace>>::``` This way you have Obj1 in one place only.

Comment: funny notation, but it works